# Here tour planning problem with time window costraint

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

i'm creating a demo to optimize some pickup and delivery job.
My dataset have different shipment that require that have a pickup and a delivery. Usually the delivery is one day later then pickup (but could be more)
For the demo, every shipment have different number of package that rapresent the demand (i don't need to take care of volume or weigth)

I created some vehicle that have a shift that should cover the entire period of the shipment, but i continue to get the time_window_costraint error.
I tried to increase the number of amount, capacity, increase duration time shift. But nothing works

```
    {
  "configuration": {
    "termination": {
      "maxTime": 30,
      "stagnationTime": 5
    }
  },
  "fleet": {
    "types": [
      {
        "id": "ffe012c5-e094-4f44-bbb0-25d68cb05b75",
        "profile": "normal_car",
        "costs": {
          "fixed": 22,
          "distance": 0.0001,
          "time": 0.0048
        },
        "shifts": [
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-04T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-04T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-04T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-04T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-05T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-05T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-05T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-05T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-06T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-06T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-06T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-06T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-07T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-07T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-07T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-07T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-08T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-08T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-08T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-08T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-09T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-09T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-09T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-09T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2021-01-10T01:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2021-01-10T23:59:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 45.45092,
                "lng": 9.11703
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2021-01-10T12:00:00Z",
                    "2021-01-10T13:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 10800
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "capacity": [
          100,
          10
        ],
        "skills": [
          "VER",
          "GRU",
          "PTT"
        ],
        "amount": 50
      }
    ],
    "profiles": [
      {
        "type": "car",
        "name": "normal_car"
      }
    ],
    "traffic": "automatic"
  },
  "plan": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": "be294863-9f3b-4e69-934d-855ffd29b18a",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-06T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-06T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                1
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.05247,
                    "lng": 10.93323
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-07T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-07T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                1
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010508591016_"
      },
      {
        "id": "c2a0cb1b-5f79-4482-a858-da5b75bd1649",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                2
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.63506,
                    "lng": 11.75273
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                2
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010709395583_"
      },
      {
        "id": "9700038f-cbc7-4267-94db-03f10852630c",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                1
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.74058,
                    "lng": 11.75615
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                1
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010709484930_"
      },
      {
        "id": "7d3fa445-30a6-46d5-99ce-40ef75ffd7d3",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                6
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 44.67897,
                    "lng": 11.03683
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                6
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010711175223_"
      },
      {
        "id": "ef7404d8-ed03-4585-8484-4ce7a596e32b",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                5
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.47498,
                    "lng": 12.23138
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                5
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010712034208_"
      },
      {
        "id": "bbba64a2-3716-4eeb-a03a-9098e8f0a844",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                4
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.74232,
                    "lng": 11.65143
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                4
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010712172566_"
      },
      {
        "id": "6d644418-88e6-40f1-a0b7-c0f9e929b794",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                12
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.52001,
                    "lng": 11.91385
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                12
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010712264327_"
      },
      {
        "id": "f42e1a9c-da42-477c-8cec-84a1116eaf55",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                6
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.52001,
                    "lng": 11.91385
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                6
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010712362396_"
      },
      {
        "id": "068a3414-8b23-4c1c-b04d-15b0e6a02b9b",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                12
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.52001,
                    "lng": 11.91385
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                12
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010712571875_"
      },
      {
        "id": "ae9a303e-8c22-44ae-ad20-0b4c94caaeea",
        "tasks": {
          "pickups": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 45.41564,
                    "lng": 9.0453
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-08T18:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-08T19:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                3
              ]
            }
          ],
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "places": [
                {
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 44.10338,
                    "lng": 12.42132
                  },
                  "duration": 1,
                  "times": [
                    [
                      "2021-01-09T10:00:00Z",
                      "2021-01-09T11:00:00Z"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "demand": [
                3
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": [
          "VER"
        ],
        "priority": 2,
        "customerId": "042021010714154753_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift maximum time can be 24 hours or 86400 seconds including break time.

Here you can see the reference

[Here Tour Planning API References](https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.7.0/api-reference-swagger.html)

its under the Fleet -> Types -> Limits -> shiftTime

> [shiftTime    number  [ 1 .. 86400 ]]
> The property shiftTime defines the maximum allowed working time of a vehicle type. In case a break is defined for this particular vehicle type, the duration of the break should be added to the shiftTime. For instance, if a vehicle type has a shift of 8 hours and a 30 minutes break, the total shiftTime should be defined as 8 hours 30 minutes. The properties start.time and end.time on the VehicleShift define the lower and upper bounds of the time interval in which the vehicle's shift must lie. Under no circumstances may a vehicle start working before start.time or finish working after end.time. The start.time and end.time can be imagined as the opening and closing times of a depot where the vehicle starts and ends its tour. start.time and end.time can override the defined shiftTime. That means, in case the time defined by the shiftTime property is longer than the time interval between start.time and end.time the maximum working time of the vehicle will be reduced and will not exceed that time interval.

Comment: In Tour planning, all the tasks in the job are required to be completed within the same shift. The pickup on day 1 and then delivery on day-2 is not supported.

However, it is possible to handle this way: the jobs should be separated as pick-ups and deliveries jobs instead of multi-job. All the pick-up jobs should be scheduled in the earlier shift and then delivery jobs should be scheduled in the later shifts.